# Sequelize not returning modified date as UTC

Tags: sequelize.js

I started using Sequelize long after we built the MySQL database. We have two columns, "created" and "modified", which store that date in which the record was created and when the record was modified.

The "created" column is of type "DATETIME", and the default value is "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". The "modified" column is of type "TIMESTAMP" with a default value of "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". MySQL stores date and time using UTC.

In our models within Sequelize, we set "timestamps: false", and configured the "created and "modified" columns as follows:

created: DataTypes.DATE,

modified: DataTypes.DATE

This allows us to pull the created and modified times when we need them, but leaves the MySQL database to record these values based upon the default values.

If I were to do a simple query, using findAll method, then within the data returned, the "created" value is return as UTC, as it is in the database. However, the "modified" value is not UTC like it is in the database, but rather two hours behind. My current timezone is two hours ahead of UTC, and it seems like Sequelize thinks that the "modified" column is in my local timezone as opposed to UTC. This is causing huge issues when we want to start manipulating data based upon the "modified" value.

Is there anything I can do to rectify this within Sequelize, or will I have to reconsider the way the database tables are configured.

Comment: do you have any example of values stored in the SQL table ? and values returned by sequelize ? timezone should usually be a display problem, but if I understand well, your sql column does not store the timezone information ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe timezone is not needed if you use UTC.

For example, my mysql server is timezone '+08:00',

"mysql2": "^1.6.4",
"sequelize": "^4.41.2"

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
    host: hostname,
    port: port,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        typeCast: function (field, next) {
            if (field.type == 'DATETIME' || field.type == 'TIMESTAMP') {
                return new Date(field.string() + 'Z');
            }
            return next();
        }
    },
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});
```

Comment: update:
You can upgrade your node package.
Eg: "mysql2": "2.0.0", "sequelize": "5.21.2",
dialectOptions is not a must.